# ForEach with NavigationLink(iOS 15)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to do NavigationLink with ForEach Loop to different views, but i can't do it.
Only what i know, that i should to change something in this code, but what and how to do it...

I tried to put RestaurantsView(i created it), but it gives me error 'cuz i don't know where to put it more properly.
Right now it gives me an empty page, but this is not a view.

```
import Foundation

enum SideMenuText: Int, CaseIterable {
    case restaurants
    case coffeeShops
    case groceryStores
    case clothingStores
    case electronicStores
    case carDealers
    
    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .restaurants: return "Restaurants"
        case .coffeeShops: return "Coffee Shops"
        case .groceryStores: return "Grocery Stores"
        case .clothingStores: return "Clothing Stores"
        case .electronicStores: return "Electronic Stores"
        case .carDealers: return "Car Dealers"
        }
    }
    
    var imageName: String {
        switch self {
        case .restaurants: return "fork.knife"
        case .coffeeShops: return "cup.and.saucer"
        case .groceryStores: return "cart"
        case .clothingStores: return "tshirt"
        case .electronicStores: return "iphone"
        case .carDealers: return "car"
        }
    }
}
```

And here:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SideMenuView: View {
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.black]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .bottom)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                SideMenuHeaderView(isShowing: $isShowing)
                
                ForEach(SideMenuText.allCases, id: \.self) { option in
                    NavigationLink ( // 
                        destination: Text(option.title),
                        label: { SideMenuOptions(viewModel: option)
                        })
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true) // 
    }
}

struct SideMenuView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SideMenuView(isShowing: .constant(true))
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't post `SideMenuOptions`, but the first thing that jumps here is that you have `label` and `destination` mixed up: you probably want to put `Text` in label, and  `SideMenuOptions` in destination: `destination: SideMenuOptions(viewModel: option),
                        label: { Text(option.title)
                        })`

Comment: @rapiddevice
I want to create for each button(restaurants, coffee shops and etc.) a View. If i tap on button "restaurants", i will go to RestaurantsView, if i tap on coffee shops, i will go to CoffeeShopsView and etc. Right now if i tap on button it gives me a View where i can't change anything, for example create there background, buttons and smth else. https://imgur.com/a/U30EtVC